# Configure Node.js application to enable CORS on specific endpoint(s) only

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, cors

I have a Node application with a number of endpoints that I am calling from JavaScript/AJAX. I have previously solved the cross origin resource sharing issue by going through a PHP proxy hosted on the same domain as the JavaScript file, but I'd like to cut out the middle-man and go direct from AJAX to Node.

I have now enabled CORS very broadly on the Node application, via:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

But this is exposing *all* endpoints, including ones I would like to remain tied to a particular domain. Can I specifically set up CORS per endpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

you can use:

```
app.use('/some/endpoint', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

If you need more control over the method, e.g. if you want CORS for GET but not for PUT or something like that, then you can also inspect the request object before adding the headers.

Comment: Thanks. Spot on ;-)